How to make task dependent on a specific task on azure pipeline yaml?
How to make task dependent on a specific task on azure pipelines?
My goal is to run tasks C and D if and only if task B failed.
I have tried using the condition: failed() but if task A failed it will run tasks C and D, which is incorrect.
Is there a way to specify which task another task is dependent on?
      - task: A
        inputs:
          command: 
          repository: 
          Dockerfile: 
          tags: 
        displayName: 'Build test image'
 
      - task: B
        inputs:
          fullImageNameAndTag: 
        displayName: 'test image'
        condition: succeeded()
 
      - task: C
        inputs:
          targetPath: 
        displayName: 'Download test image'
        condition: ?

      - task: D
        inputs:
          targetPath: 
        displayName: 'Download test2 image'
        condition: ?


What is the task type of B? If it's a script it might be possible to set a pipeline variable and then use a condition in C and D to check its value.

task type of B is prisma scan

Did any of the below answers work?

@生きがい, As suggested in my answer below, you can use the API "Timeline - Get" to get the status of the task and use the logging command "SetVariable" to set the task status as a pipeline variable for use on the condition of subsequent tasks.

This should do the trick - uncomment lines # exit 1 to fail a specific task:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "This is task A"
      # exit 1
    displayName: 'Task A'
    # Allow the following tasks to run, in case of failure
    # If task is successful then $(Agent.JobStatus)=Succeeded
    # If task fails then $(Agent.JobStatus)=SucceededWithIssues
    continueOnError: true 

  - script: |
      echo "This is task B"
      # exit 1
    displayName: 'Task B'
    condition: eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded')
    
  - script: |
      echo "This is task C"
    displayName: 'Task C'
    condition: failed() # same as eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed')
  
  - script: |
      echo "This is task D"
    displayName: 'Task D'
    condition: failed() # same as eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed')

Notes:

Task A: continueOnError: true allows the following tasks to run if the task fails, but sets variable Agent.JobStatus=SucceededWithIssues
Task B: Runs only if task A is successful, i.e. variable Agent.JobStatus==Succeeded
Tasks C and D: Run if task B fails, i.e. variable Agent.JobStatus==Failed

See Job status check functions.

can you please elaborate more about this on this part of the conditioncondition: eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded') what does it do?

@生きがい task A has continueOnError: true - this means that if it fails then Agent.JobStatus=SucceededWithIssues. Task B will run if and only if task A is successful. See Job status check functions

Please note that condition succeeded() is equivalent to in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues')

@生きがい was my explanation clear enough...?

yes it's clear now thank you for the assistance @Rui Jarimba

You can use the Azure DevOps REST API "Timeline - Get" to get the status of the Task B ('test image'):

Use the API "Timeline - Get" the get the status of the Task B.

Use the logging command "SetVariable" to set the task status as a pipeline variable for use.

On Task C and D, use the condition key determine whether run the two task based on the status of the Task B.


steps:
# Task A
- task: A
  displayName: 'Build test image'
  . . .

# Task B
- task: B
  displayName: 'test image'
  . . .

# Get status of Task B
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Check task status'
  condition: always()
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    pwsh: true
    script: |
      $organizationUri = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
      $project = "$(System.TeamProject)"
      $buildId = $(Build.BuildId)
      $uri = "${organizationUri}${project}/_apis/build/builds/${buildId}/timeline?api-version=7.0"
      $headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
      $taskResult = ($response.records | where {$_.name -eq "test image"}).result
      Write-Host "Task 'test image' is $taskResult."
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=taskStatus;]$taskResult"

# Task C
- task: C
  displayName: 'Download test image'
  condition: eq(variables.taskStatus, 'failed')
  . . .

# Task D
- task: D
  displayName: 'Download test2 image'
  condition: eq(variables.taskStatus, 'failed')
  . . .

With this way:

If Task B is failed, Task C and D will run.
If Task B is succeeded, Task C and D will not run.
If Task A is failed, Task B gets skipped, Task C and D will not run.



